# Model selection for panel data (Pooled or Panel models)

Tags: panel-data, stata, heteroscedasticity, breusch-pagan

Can I use Breusch-Pagan test to decide whether to use pooled or panel models? Few people use Standard LM test for this purpose. I am using stata.